# variable or tag

Tags: html

hello I never understand the difference between a variable and a tag. Can anybody help me? Is there one at all and how bad is it if you mix them up?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This needs a lot more context - strictly speaking, there are neither variables nor tags in CSS (well, variables at least not in run-off-the-mill CSS2). Can you show some examples of what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the friendly hello! This is a little embarassing. I am actually a translator working on a document that deals with HTML programming. The document describes various methods of creating HTML pages and how you can access the variables (well or tags for that matter) of the HMI to be able to do this. I just didn't exactly know where to post my query.

Comment: I've retagged your question as HTML. HTML has "tags" (also known as "elements"). However, it doesn't have variables either. Are you talking about JavaScript?

Comment: Please post an excerpt you're struggling to translate into your question. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense from your description. ;)

Comment: Which language are you translating from or to?

Comment: would love to post some but would be a) too comprehensive and b) illegal (not allowed to pass it on). Assuming it is tags I am talking about and there are no variables - meaning that those tags are like commands or instructions to do things, can you also say tag declarations. I thought only variable declarations existed. God this must sound seriously weird. Hope this makes any sense at all.

Comment: I am translating from German to English. Sometimes the text uses the English "tag" but sometimes it uses "Variable" (the German Variable) that is part of my problem. It seems to be interchanged without much logic behind it

Comment: I think the main question is what programming language the text is discussing? Is it CSS (as per your original question), or HTML (as it has been edited to)? Or is it discussing both of them? Does it also include Javascript? The term "tag" implies HTML, but "variable" suggests possibly Javascript. But we really need to know more context before we can give much real assistance.

Comment: Hi Spudley, your question has actually helped me. It is dealing with both, CSS and HTML but no Javascript. I guess if I stick to tags and avoid the word variables altogether i shoud be on the save side? It is only that the term "tag declaration" comes up - I thought that you could only have "variable declarations" but I was obviously wrong about that one. Thank to all for your time

Answer (score 2):

An example of tags would be all the `<bracketed>` things in this HTML snippet:

```
<p>This is a sentence with <em>tags</em>. Tags add <b>meaning</b> to text.</p>
```

The tags add meaning to the text (*"this is a `<p>`aragraph"*, *"this should be `<em>`phasized"*, *"this should be `<b>`old"*). Any consumer (any program or human reading this text) may do with it what he likes. A web browser would choose to render the text like so:

> This is a sentence with *tags*. Tags add **meaning** to text.

Other consumers may display the text as-is including the tags, or may discard the tags. Tags that do not exist as part of an agreed standard are ignored. As such tags can't be *declared*, they're just *used*.

Variables are a mathematical thing and do not exist in HTML. HTML is a *passive markup language*. Variables OTOH are used in calculations and computations:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
var c = a + b;
b = 42;
```

`a`, `b` and `c` are variables that *hold values*. Variables are *declared* into existence (`var a`), they do not exist before you declare that you want to use them and their names are completely arbitrary (as opposed to HTML tags, which are agreed upon in advance in the HTML spec). Their value *varies* (e.g. the value of `b` changes from 10 to 42), hence "variables".

---

CSS is sort of a mix. In CSS, you can *declare* **styles**:

```
.foobar {
    text-size: 200%;
}
```

This says that any HTML element (tag) with the *class* "foobar" should have a text size of 200%. This is *declared* arbitrarily, i.e. you can choose any name for `.foobar` and add new styles at any time. There aren't any variables in standard CSS though.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry deceze, missed your answer at first. This also really helped me a lot. Cheers.